# jQuery code not works

Tags: jquery

I want to corrected next jQuery code but i don't know how.

```
jQuery('#jud').change(function(){
    if (jQuery("#jud").val() == "0") {
        jQuery(".loc").hide();
       } else {
        jQuery(".loc").show();
    }
jQuery("#loc").find("option").hide();
jQuery("#loc").find("option[name =" + jQuery(this).attr("name") + "]").show();
});
```

This code display corresponding options in second select which has the same name options in the first select and hides the rest

```
<select id="jud">
<option name="0">Select</option>
<option name="1">Jud1</option>
<option name="2">Jud2</option>
</select>

<div class="loc">
<select id="loc">
<option name="0">Select</option>
<option name="1">Loc1</option>
<option name="1">loc2</option>
<option name="2">loc3</option>
<option name="2">loc3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

i think the problem is here `if (jQuery("#jud").val() == "0")`

can you help me?

Comment: your html is not well formed..``<options>`` is not valid ``<option>`` is valid

Comment: please share jsfiddle ..

Comment: `jQuery(this).attr("name")`  is not going to find the name of the selected option. You really should be using value and it is option, not options.

Comment: i need to make dinamic using name, not value

Comment: @mIH1 I have posted the solution for you in Answers. PLease check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7UZU/

Also posting the code below:

HTML:

```
<select id="jud">
<option name="0">Select</option>
<option name="1">Jud1</option>
<option name="2">Jud2</option>
</select>

<div class="loc">
<select id="loc">
<option name="0" >Select</option>
<option name="1" style="display:none;">Loc1</option>
<option name="1" style="display:none;">loc2</option>
<option name="2" style="display:none;">loc3</option>
<option name="2" style="display:none;">loc4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('#jud').change(function(){

    var secN = $(this).find(':selected').attr('name');

    $('#loc option').hide();
    $('#loc option[name='+secN+']').show();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

try taking selected option value (edited, as haven't seen you are using names instead of values for option tag):

```
$("#jud option:selected").attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not correct. You should use `value` attributes instead of `name`s.

```
jQuery('#jud').change(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).val() == "0") {
        jQuery(".loc").hide();
    } else {
        jQuery(".loc").show();
    }
    jQuery("#loc").find("option").hide();
    jQuery("#loc").find("option[value=" + jQuery(this).val() + "]").show();
});
```

Javascript also can be simplified:

```
$('#jud').change(function () {
    $(".loc").toggle($(this).val() != "0");
    $("#loc option").hide().filter("[value =" + $(this).val() + "]").show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dam6v/